# Read a text file(having some words) in spark as regex and check if any of the regex from the file matches a string?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I am reading a file which contains few words as below:

words in file

```
 .*pay.*
 .*netpay.*
```

read Data

```
val regex_data = "/junk/keywords.txt"
val kw = sc.textFile(regex_data).flatMap(line => line.split("\n")).map(x => x.toUpperCase).map(x => x.r).collect
```

Now I want to check if any of these `kw` matches my string. I am not sure how to approach with the matching part.
any help appreciated.

Comment: "contains" helps? val result = kw.filter(line => line.contains("your search string"))

Comment: <console>:32: error: value contains is not a member of scala.util.matching.Regex
       kw.filter(line => line.contains("pay))

Comment: You could hard code the regex `(?:netpay|pay)`. And, probably don't need the `.*`'s unless the search engine requires a full string match.

Comment: @sln, can you please tell in little more detail as what needs to be done

Comment: Some pretty easy examples [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_regular_expressions.htm) for using regex in Scala. So, something like `new Regex(netpay|pay)` Note- I had to refresh the page after clicking the link.